# How to build a new dictionary with values from two different dictionaries having same keys

Tags: c#, dictionary, indexoutofrangeexception

Let's say we have two dictionaries with the following key pair values:

- Dictionary 1 : [ {1,abc} {2,cde} {3,efg} ]
- Dictionary 2:  [ {1,123} {2,234} {3,345} ]
- I want to create a dictionary as follows:
  Dictionary 3 : [ {abc,123} {cde,234} {efg,345} ]

  ```
      fieldValues = new List<List<string>>();
      docFieldKey = new List<List<string>>();
      docFieldValueDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
      docKeyDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
      iterateDocKeyDict = new List<string>();
      iterateDocFldValueDict = new List<string>();

      //To read row wise and store key and all values
      for (limit = 0; limit < docNames.Count; limit++)
      {
          for (row = 0; row < excelData.Count; row++)
          {
              if (excelData[row] == docNames[limit])
              {
                  for (colLimit = row + 1; colLimit < fieldNames.Count; colLimit++)
                  {
                      flag = true;
                      fieldValues.Add(new List<string>());
                      fieldValues[limit].Add(excelData[colLimit]);
                  }
                  if (flag == true)
                  {
                      docFieldValueDict.Add(docNames[limit], fieldValues[limit]);                          
                  }
              }
          }

      }

      //To add concatenated key for each docName
      for (limit = 0; limit < docNames.Count; limit++)
      {
          for (colLimit = 0; colLimit < concatKey.Count; colLimit++)
          {
              if (concatKey[colLimit].Contains(docNames[limit]))
              {
                  for (col = colLimit; col < fieldNames.Count - 1; col++)
                  {
                      flag = true;
                      docFieldKey.Add(new List<string>());
                      docFieldKey[limit].Add(concatKey[col]);
                  }
                  if (flag == true)
                  {
                      docKeyDict.Add(docNames[limit], docFieldKey[limit]);
                  }
              }
          }

      }

      //to merge the key and the value from both dictionaries
      for (limit = 0; limit <docKeyDict.Count; limit++)
      {
          var docKeyDictCompare = docKeyDict.ElementAt(limit);
          var docFldValueDictCompare = docFieldValueDict.ElementAt(limit);
          iterateDocKeyDict = docKeyDictCompare.Value;
          iterateDocFldValueDict = docFldValueDictCompare.Value;
          if (docKeyDictCompare.Key == docFldValueDictCompare.Key)
          {
              for (col = 0; col < fieldNames.Count - 1; col++)
              {
                  if ((iterateDocKeyDict.ElementAt(col)!=string.Empty) && (iterateDocFldValueDict.ElementAt(col)!=string.Empty))
                  {
                      flag = true;
                  }
              }

              if (flag == true)
              {
                  keyValuePairDict.Add(iterateDocKeyDict.ElementAt(col), iterateDocFldValueDict.ElementAt(col));
              }
          }
      }
  ```

I tried the above but I get index out of range exception at

`if ((iterateDocKeyDict.ElementAt(col)!=string.Empty) &&(iterateDocFldValueDict.ElementAt(col)!=string.Empty))`
[Error msg displayed in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFMcj.png)

Comment: So.. You want `Dictionary<int, string>` and `Dictionary<int, int>` to a `Dictionary<string, int>`..  The string should be the Key.

Comment: Actually all the three dicitonary keys are of the type string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just looking at your sample dictionaries I would suggest this:

```
var dic1 = /* [ {1,abc} {2,cde} {3,efg} ] */;
var dic2 = /* [ {1,123} {2,234} {3,345} ] */;
var dic3 = dic1.ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => dic2[x.Key]);
```

But looking at your fairly long code sample I'm not sure it is enough.

Comment: I'd also add something like `.Where(x => dic2.ContainsKey(x)).`

Comment: @Sinatr True. I assumed the keys would always be availabe by working from the examples. An existence check would be a good addition.

Comment: Might want to group by the values of the first dictionary to make sure there are no duplicates (take the first key for duplicates maybe).

Comment: @juharr True as well. Again, this is the simplest solution which you can create, and lots of checks can be added. This solves the most basic problem that the OP is having.

Comment: @Maarten Agreed.  I didn't even bother to see if the OP is trying to make those checks in their code, but thought it should be pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
var dictionaryC = dictionaryA.ToDictionary(dicA => dicA.Value, dicA => dictionaryB[dicA.Key]);
```