# C# Create a Dictionary from List<Dictionary>

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics, dictionary

I has a list of dictionaries, like:

```
dic1.Add("A_key1","A_val11"); dic1.Add("B_key1","B_val11")
dic1.Add("C","C"); dic1.Add("D","D");

dic2.Add("A_key1","A_val21");  dic1.Add("B_key1","B_val21");
dic2.Add("C","C");  dic1.Add("D","D");
dic2.Add("A_key2","A_val22");  dic1.Add("B_key2","B_val22");
dic2.Add("A_key3","A_val23");  dic1.Add("B_key3","B_val23");

List<Dictionary<string,string>> tempList = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>{dic1, dic2};
```

I need to create a Dictionary from tempList follow rule: key = "A_key*" value, val = "B_key*" value from all original Dictionaries in list.
Eg, In above example:

```
expectDic = {("A_val11","B_val11"),
              ("A_val21","A_val21"),
              ("A_val22","A_val22"),
              ("A_val23","A_val23")}
```

Can I resolve it with Linq?

Comment: A combination of `SelectMany` and `ToDictionary` might do the trick

Comment: Are there ever going to be only 2 dictionaries? and what about items that don't have matching keys in both dictionaries?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351583/how-to-build-a-new-dictionary-with-values-from-two-different-dictionaries-having)?

Comment: Not really clear.Apart from the first entry the key and values are the same. Can you explain it better?

Comment: Missing dic2. Edited

Comment: @tamhoang: the expected dictionary still seems to be broken. Why contains it values that start with `A_`? Does the key and value have the same string behind `_`?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter : I need to get value only. Edited the question

Comment: @Manfred Radlwimmer: could you explain more?

Comment: @tamhoang Dictionaries are `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` so can can flatten all dictionaries together as needed with `SelectMany`, modify/merge whatever you want and build your final result with `ToDictionary`

Comment: Why do you want to do this with linq? Solve your problem with whatever solution is best to do the job. That may or may not be linq. If it's easier for you to solve it without linq, why don't you? If your question is really about learning linq, then say so. But even in that case, it may help you (and us) to understand the problem better if you provide non-linq code that does the same. You could even use it to write a unit test for your linq code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear so I'm going to make a few assumptions. If these assumptions are incorrect, then let me know and ill modify as appropriate.

Going off your test data, because the keys will be the same, merging the dictionaries will not be possible, hence the list.

Finally, your test data in itself is incorrect as it throws an exception. Thus, I made the assumption that the test data was the following:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Dictionary<string, string> dic2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        dic1.Add("A_1", "A_val11");
        dic1.Add("B_1", "B_val11");
        dic1.Add("C", "C");
        dic1.Add("D", "D");


        dic2.Add("A_1", "A_val21");
        dic2.Add("A_2", "A_val22");
        dic2.Add("A_3", "A_val23");
        dic2.Add("B_1", "B_val21");
        dic2.Add("B_2", "B_val22");
        dic2.Add("B_3", "B_val23");
        dic2.Add("C", "C");
        dic2.Add("D", "D");


        List<Dictionary<string, string>> tempList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>> { dic1, dic2 };
```

Here is some code which will work for the given example:

```
Dictionary<string, string> expectDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < tempList.Count; i++)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> onedic = tempList[i];
            while (onedic.Values.ToList().Where(x => x.Contains("A_")).FirstOrDefault() != null)
            {
                expectDic.Add(onedic.Select(x => x.Value).Where(x => x.Contains("A_") && !expectDic.Keys.Contains(x)).First(), onedic.Select(x => x.Value).Where(x => x.Contains("B_") && !expectDic.Values.Contains(x)).First());
                onedic.Remove(onedic.Select(x => x.Key).Where(x => x.Contains("A_")).FirstOrDefault());
                onedic.Remove(onedic.Select(x => x.Key).Where(x => x.Contains("B_")).FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }
```

However, what you are asking for is very complicated and I would recommend exception handling for the LINQ.